# Python script outputs dictionary data in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

I am writing a script to check for an overlap of IDs between two files, and in Windows it is able to output the file path for a list of IDs from a dictionary of {ID:filepath}. However, in my Linux server, there is no output.

```
CELs=[]
CELpaths = {}
f=open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
data = f.read()
lines = data.split('\n')[1:-1]
for line in lines:
    tabs = line.split('\\')
    CELs.append(tabs[-1])

    CELpaths[(tabs[-1])]=line

yyid = []
f2=open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
data2=f2.read()
lines2=data2.split('\n')

for x in lines2:
    yyid.append(x)

for c in yyid:
    if c in CELpaths:
        print (CELpaths[c])
```

The problem definitely lies in the "for c in yyid:" segment, where Python on my Linux server is not able to perform the line "if c in CELs:". My Linux is running Python 2.7, while my Windows is running Python 3. Is this simply a version problem? Is there a way to fix the syntax to allow for output on my Linux?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the line endings on the input file consistent across Windows and Linux? On Linux, maybe try '\r ' instead of '\n'?

Comment: Isn't your problem caused by different path separators between Windows & Linux ? I see a `line.split('\\')`, the backslash is windows-specific.

Comment: @user1451348 thanks, \r was exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably have less problems using the proper way to read a file line by line (which is symply to iterate over the file object), using `line.strip()` (without arguments) to remove the newline character (whatever it is), and remembering that in Python "\" is an escape char so "\" is actually "\" (if you want two backslashes, use a raw string ie `r"\\"`).

Also, Python doesn't garantee that opened files will be closed, so you must take care of it to.

Untested (of course since you didn't not post your source data), but this is is mostly the pythonic equivalent of your script:

```
def main(p1, p2):
    CELs=[]
    CELpaths = {}

    with open(p1) as f:
        # skip first line
        f.next() 
        for line in f:
            # remove trailing whitespaces (including the newline character) 
            line = line.rstrip() 
            # I assume the `data[1:-1] was to skip an empty last line
            if not line:
                continue
            # If you want a single backward slash, 
            # this would be better expressed as `r'\'`
            # If you want two, you should use `r'\\'.
            # AND if it's supposed to be a platform-dependant
            # filesystem path separator, you should be using
            # `os.path.sep` and/or `os.path` functions.  
            tabs = line.split('\\')
            CELs.append(tabs[-1])
            CELpaths[(tabs[-1])] = line

    with open(p2) as f:
        # no need to store the whole stuff in memory
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line in CELpaths:
                print (CELpaths[line])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    p1, p2 = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    main(p1, p2)
```

I can't of course garantee it will solve your problem since you didn't provide a MCVE...